# Negative value of margin

Tags: css

I have a box that has another box in it, similar to a sidebar. However, whatever height I set for the sidebar box it won't go on top and merge with the other one. The only solution I found is to set a margin-top negative value but that won't really work as I would like to since I don't have a fixed height for .box_stanga. Please note that #recent_vizualizate is the name of the sidebar and .box_stanga is the name of its container box. Both are contained in the #wrapper. Here is the code:

```
.box_stanga
{
    margin-top: 5%;
    padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px #999999; 
    border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
    background-color:white;
    width: 100%;

}

#recent_vizualizate
{
    top: 0px;
    float: right;
    /*margin-left: 20%;*/
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px #999999; 
    border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: -600px;
}

#wrapper{width:1080px; margin:0 auto;}
```

Generated HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>RevelioninRomania.ro</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/animated_favicon1.gif">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="photo/css/ReMooz.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="photo/css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="photo/css/jd.gallery.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="photo/scripts/mootools-1.2.1-core-yc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="photo/scripts/mootools-1.2-more.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="photo/scripts/jd.gallery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>




</head>
<body>

<!-- Meniu -->
<tr><td style="vertical-align:top">
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="index.php" class="active"><span><b>Cauta oferta</b></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="adauga.php"><span><b>Adauga oferta</b></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.php"><span><b>Contact</b></span></a></li>
</ul>
</tr></td>
<div id="wrapper">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function startGallery() {
                var myGallery = new gallery($('myGallery'), {
                    timed: true
                });
            }
            window.addEvent('domready',startGallery);
        </script>
                <br>
            <div class="box_stanga">
            <div id="myGallery">
                                <div class="imageElement">              
                    <a href="#" title="open image" class="open"></a>
                    <img src="photo/images/5207ffe15b8d8/1.jpg" style="width:480px; height:345px;"  />
                    <img src="photo/images/5207ffe15b8d8/1-mini.jpg" class="thumbnail" />
                </div>

            </div>

        <br/><br/><br/><br/><h1 >Lupul Vesel</h1><br/>Restaurant<br/>Judet: Gorj<br/>Localitate: Targu-Jiu<br/>Strada: <br/>Numar: 0<br/>Telefon: <br/>Fax: <br/>E-mail: <br/>Website: <br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br/><br/><div id='recent_vizualizate'><p class='center'>Recent vizualizate</p></div></div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='javascript:history.back()'><img src='images/back.png' id='back'></a><br/>       </div>

        <div id="footer">
    Acest site nu salveaza date de tip cookie in calculatorul dumneavoastra. Copyright &copy; 2013 - 2013 RevelioninRomania.ro. Toate drepturile rezervate.
</div>  </body>
</html>
```

The other divs that you're seeing are for the photo gallery, they don't affect the sidebar in any way.

Please let me know if you need anything alse or if I need to edit my post instead of downvoting. Thanks!

Comment: Post also the related html code. and then make a fiddle if possible.

Comment: Giving margin-top and margin-bottom values in percentages is not recommended because the percentage value will be respect to the **width** of the parent element but not the **height**.

Comment: If you're looking to place an element outside of its current position, use position:fixed or position:absolute. And yes, fiddle please.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving it a position of relative.  Like so:

```
.box_stanga
{
    margin-top: 5%;
    padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px #999999; 
    border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
    background-color:white;
    width: 100%;

}

#recent_vizualizate
{
    top: -600px;
    float: right;
    /*margin-left: 20%;*/
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px #999999; 
    border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    /* -- margin-top: -600px; -- Do Not Use */
    position: relative;
}

#wrapper{width:1080px; margin:0 auto;}
```

I haven't tested that out, but let me know if that works for you.  It would be best if you use 'px' for your height and width as well as for your margins.

Comment: The same effect is produced. Is there no way to define a height of 100% to the recent_vizualizate id and make it take the height of its parent box_stanga class?

Comment: So your parent is .box_stanga?  If that's the case, specify a height for the parent element and simply make the child element have a height of auto.  Let me know if that helps ;)